# Opening hours in Maastricht, the Netherlands, for first day of year

Tags: public-holidays, maastricht

I am planning a trip in Maastricht for the first day of the year.

Are there shops and the cafes are open during this holiday?

Comment: Any particular type of shops and cafés you're interested in?

Answer (score 3):

If a place in the Netherlands is closed two days in the year, it will be Christmas day and New Years Day.
Not everything will be closed but enough that I would not consider going to sight see or club in any town or city in the Netherlands.

I checked out a few of the main museums in Maastricht, which are mostly a good indication, and non of them is open on January First.

And [city information site](http://www.vvvmaastricht.nl/en/shopping/opening-hours.html) even mentions the few days the shops are closed, those include the first day of the year.